# cannot enable mysqli on joomla

Tags: joomla, mysqli, shared-hosting, hostmonster

I have a shared hosting account on Hostmonster, on which I just installed the Joomla CMS. I also added a plugin which I just found out requires MySQLi driver to function properly.

So I did some googling which advided me to change a few minimum required settings in PHP.ini and also added the mysqli extention with

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

but when I change the database setting in Joomla to MySQLi the Save button doesn't respond.

I have checked all minimum requirements and am very sure I meet all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a look at the [hostmonster website](http://www.hostmonster.com/cgi/info/hosting_features) and it looks like they only offer linux hosting.
If this is the case then your extension line should be

```
extension=php_mysqli.so
```

The '.dll' extension only applies to Windows.

Comment: thanks Jez, that helped, but also was a problem with joomla itself. The Config page did not register the change of the drop down box where you have to choose MySQLi so the save button didn't work until I entered a site name. How rubbish! :)